# jQuery Validation Plugin Response Messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am creating a JavaScript / ajax comment form using the jQuery Validation Plugin.

How do I customize the messages that are sent to the user? Currently, the form returns `heuristic type: NAME_FULL server type: NO_SERVER_DATA field signature: 3489289364 form signature: 13828296746807249018 experiment id:""` when a field is left blank.

I just want it to say "Please enter your name." Here is the JavaScript that controls the plugin and the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").submit(function(){
        if($("#commentForm").validate()){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(returnedData){
                $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});

 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
     <input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
     <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
```

And the php is pretty straightforward:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 

print "E-mail is correct";

$to      = 'asdfdsafasdfsda@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

} else {
print "E-mail is not correct";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "This field is required.",
        remote: "Please fix this field.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
        date: "Please enter a valid date.",
        dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
        number: "Please enter a valid number.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits.",
        creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
        accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
        minlength: $.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
        rangelength: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
        range: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
        max: $.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
        min: $.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Proper implementation of Validation Plugin...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#commentForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(returnedData) {
                    $(this).append(returnedData);
                }
            });         
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

[Validation Plugin Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: @NickB, you don't call it.  Simply put it inside the `document.ready` along with everything else and it runs when the page loads, over-riding the plugin defaults.

Comment: Thank you @Sparky672. I am having some problems getting this to work with the form that I have set up, however. I am still getting "heuristic type" ajax response rather than "please enter a valid email." Although the script is basically from jquery, I'll post more of my script above and maybe you could catch my error.

Comment: @NickB, On second look, you're not using the Validation plugin correctly.  There are handlers built into it that take care of submission, so you don't have to bind the validate function inside of a submit handler.  When I get back later today, I'll provide a lengthy example.

Comment: @NickB: When you want to test to see if a form is valid, you would use the `.valid()` method.  However, since a `submitHandler` is already built into the plugin, just use that instead.  If the form is valid, it runs your ajax, if not, it throw the error messages.  See my edits.

Comment: thank you for the help with the validation plugin. Its working properly now. Your awesome.